# Failed to convert string to int - Application stops

Tags: android, string, android-studio

I need a big help ..

I am using a simple code to convert String to Int and when I emulate the speech that the application stops, I do not understand the reason, I have tried converting it in several ways, but when I run the emulator or on my smartphone the application does not even open, .

```
package development.idea.tisco.reformaprevidencia;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // DECLARANDO COMPONENTES

    private RadioGroup grupo;
    private EditText idade;
    private EditText inss;
    private TextView pontos;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // VINCULANDO COMPONENTES

        grupo = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_group_id);
        idade = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.idade_id);
        inss = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inss_id);
        pontos = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pontos_id);


        // CAPTURANDO STRING

        String textoIdade = idade.getText().toString();
        String textoInss = inss.getText().toString();

        // CONVERTENDO PARA NUMERO

        int valorIdade = Integer.parseInt(textoIdade);
        int valorInss = Integer.parseInt(textoInss);


    }
}
```

I hope you can help me.

Thank you so much.

Comment: post stacktrace

Comment: Are your EditTexts `textoIdade` and `textoInss` empty when your app starts? Because if so then that's your problem.

Comment: If you are writing these all at onCreate method, textoIdade and textoInss variables will be null, and calling Integer.parseInt(null) will cause null pointer or parse exception when runtime.

Comment: what do you think `idade.getText().toString()` does? better yet, what did you observe during your debugging that `idade.getText().toString()` actually is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would bet that you are getting a [`NumberFormatException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) as you're passing an empty `String` into `Integer.parseInt()`. You can avoid this by wrapping the `parseInt` statements with a [`TextUtils.isDigitsOnly()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isDigitsOnly(java.lang.CharSequence)) check.

For example:

```
int valorIdade = 0;
int valorInss = 0;

if (TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(textoIdade)) {
    valorIdade = Integer.parseInt(texttoIdade);
}

if (TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(textoInss)) {
    valorInss = Integer.parseInt(textoInss);
}
```

So your full class would be as follows:

```
package development.idea.tisco.reformaprevidencia;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.text.TextUtils;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // DECLARANDO COMPONENTES

    private RadioGroup grupo;
    private EditText idade;
    private EditText inss;
    private TextView pontos;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // VINCULANDO COMPONENTES

        grupo = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radio_group_id);
        idade = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.idade_id);
        inss = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inss_id);
        pontos = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pontos_id);


        // CAPTURANDO STRING

        String textoIdade = idade.getText().toString();
        String textoInss = inss.getText().toString();

        // CONVERTENDO PARA NUMERO
        int valorIdade = 0;
        int valorInss = 0;

        if (TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(textoIdade)) {
            valorIdade = Integer.parseInt(texttoIdade);
        }

        if (TextUtils.isDigitsOnly(textoInss)) {
            valorInss = Integer.parseInt(textoInss);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 int valorIdade,valorInss;
   if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(textoIdade)){
      int valorIdade = Integer.parseInt(textoIdade);
    }
          if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(textoInss)){
      valorInss = Integer.parseInt(textoInss);
    }
```

Comment: Problem there is that you'd need to declare `valorIdade` and `valorInss` outside of the `if` statements, else the IDE will complain about trying to access a variable that may not have been declared.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check your "Android Monitor" tab in android studio to see what exception your application throws and causes the application to stop.
Also, I guess the problem is where you are using Integer.parseInt(). This method does not parse a string which is not fully digit numbers. for example:

```
Integer.parseInt("some text"); // throws java.lang.NumberFormatException
Integer.parseInt("1245");  // this one works without error
```

By the way, it is better if you wrap the part of your code which will throw exceptions in try/catch and log error somewhere (like android monitor) to prevent application from crashing